# Principles to be applied in creating a template

Tags: gui-design

Our team objective is to prevent hospital visits. First step is to prevent the second visit for the same illness, at least in the first 96 hours. The rationale is, a viral fever will last upto 120 hours, cold upto 10 days and cough upto 14 days.If parents of sick children are educated well in the first visit, they will not come unless there are "warning symptoms" or "red flags".  First step is to comprehensive  health record. Both which can be filled by para medical workers and by physicians, have a common feature. They use the same set of words again and again. For example, in describing the status of child there are only 7 points which strike a person on the first look. 1. Active. alert interested in surroundings 2. Sleeping but  3. Crying 4.Irritbale 5. whimpering. 6. Moaning 7. Lethargic. Each one of the condition has an implication in a fever case, particularly, in children below one year. In creating a template for this, under physical examination, I wanted it in alphabetical order, so that when the first alphabet is typed the choice also comes, as all the 7 choices have different first letter. 
My question: what principles govern a template creation? For references, which link you will recommend? At the age of 56, the best way to proceed in system development, is to ask the correct road, and travel.

Comment: answer accepted with gratitude

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have 7 points, why not to create 7 big boxes with an icon for each? People in general love images. It's quicker to scan a list of options once you have a visual aid.

Also, someone could type a synonym for whimpering or active, and in that case you'd return no results, which is not good.

You have the benefit of having just a limited number of options, leverage that and show them all, with visual aid :)

Here is an example from a design I did recently:

[image]

Comment: +1 for icons. These can also reduce ambiguity in this context and improve accessibility. _Irritable_, _Moaning_ or _Whimpering_ could be subjective. Adding icons would help greatly by adding physical characteristics to look for (tears, mouth open, etc)

Comment: Thank you, after a month I got the answer as well as ways to express ideas on paper

Comment: another thanks for steps to reduce ambiguity. I have trouble in classifiying cough. what is severe for me may mild for some one. for pain we have 10 icons for patients to choose. I think I will try for cough